# call a script after a page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table which is filled from several jsp pages.
I wanna alternate the table `<tr>` background after the page is loaded.

I have to call this script:

```
function alternate(id){ 
    var table = document.getElementById(id);   
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");   
    for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){  
        if(i % 2 == 0){ 
            rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "#84939a"; 
          }else{ 
            rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
          }      
    }
    }
```

How can I do that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your `<script>` just before the closing `</body>` tag and call it:

```
<script>
function alternate(id){ 
var table = document.getElementById(id);   
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");   
for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){  
    if(i % 2 == 0){ 
        rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "#84939a"; 
      }else{ 
        rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
      }      
}
}
alternate();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are using JQuery you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

.. your code

});
```

but doing alternating colors is much simpler with css

```
tr:nth-child(odd)       { background-color:#84939a; }
tr:nth-child(even)      { background-color:#FFFFFF; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onload = function() {alternate(id)};
```

Just make sure to replace `id` with the id you want wrapped in quotes.